# How can i automate message sending using microsoft graphQL in C#?

Tags: c#, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-teams

I wanted to build an app in C# that'll be able to send messages to people on teams based on some triggers, I was unable to get started with that app. I would be great if you could provide me with a starting point.

I tried Documentation and other AI tools but didnt understand much about it.

Comment: That's really broad. But maybe start by breaking that huge junk of a project into smaller pieces and nibble away on the parts. For example: Why not start off with a "dumb" Console Program, that lets you send a Message to a Teams Chat from the Console? That way you'll learn about Teams-Interaction without all the other fuzz. Then when you have mastered that to some degree, think about what you can solve next. Maybe "Do _something_ based on 'some triggers'". When that works, you can combine the two ...